# ATTiny84A and RFM12B module isn't working with RF12

Tags: c++, attiny

I’m doing a project where I need to send some data between to devices with a RFM12B transceiver. I’m using the RF12-library with the pingPong example – nothing is modified.

My microcontroller is ATTiny84A and the wiring can be seen [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4zIc.jpg)

My problem is that it simply doesn’t work. The initialize seems to work. The first few seconds rf12_canSend() also returns true, but after that it returns false. My guess is that it starts to send some data but for some reason it can’t. I have no clue about what the problem is but my only guess would be that it isn’t using the right pins but I’ve followed the example.

Ignore the LED, it’s for testing.